# Can we say that: $ \sum_{n\geq k}{\frac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}}}\leq \frac{2}{k^\alpha} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $S_k=\sum_{n\geq k}{\frac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}}}$ with $\alpha >0$ and $k\geq 1$. Can we say that:
$$
S_k\leq \frac{2}{k^\alpha}
$$
If not, can you give me an Upper bound of $S_k$?

Comment: See Tuvasbien's answer below. A sharper bound is as follows: $$
\sum\limits_{n = k}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^{1 + \alpha } }}}  \le \sum\limits_{n = k}^\infty  {\int_{n - 1/2}^{n + 1/2} {\frac{{dt}}{{t^{1 + \alpha } }}} }  = \int_{k - 1/2}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{dt}}{{t^{1 + \alpha } }}}  = \frac{1}{{\alpha (k - 1/2)^\alpha  }}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$ S_k\leqslant\sum_{n=k}^{+\infty}\int_{n-1}^n\frac{dx}{x^{1+\alpha}}=\int_{k-1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{1+\alpha}}=\frac{1}{\alpha(k-1)^{\alpha}} $$
We don't have $S_k\leqslant\frac{2}{k^{\alpha}}$ in general, indeed let $\alpha\rightarrow 0$ we would have $$\lim\limits_{\alpha\rightarrow 0}\sum_{n\geqslant k}\frac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}}\leqslant 2$$
for all $k\in\mathbb{N}^*$ which is not because $\lim\limits_{\alpha\rightarrow 0}\zeta(1+\alpha)=+\infty$.